# SQL Duplicating Data--

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have several wrap statements that are retreiving integer values and inside the wrap statements, the values are being calculated fine...It's when I want to SELECT multiple integer values from different wrap statements that I am getting the problem...The duplication differs with each val, sometime I am getting a value that is EXACTLY 200 times larger than it should be.

Here is how the code structure looks,

```
  SELECT
       SUM(c.val)
      ,SUM(t.val)
      ,SUM(x.val)
      ,SUM(z.val)
   FROM    
    (SELECT CASE
        WHEN ------CRITERIA FOR CODE HERE
    FROM tableName
    WHERE ...
    )c,

    (SELECT CASE
    WHEN ------CRITERIA FOR CODE HERE
    FROM tableName
    WHERE ...
    )t,

   (SELECT CASE
    WHEN ------CRITERIA FOR CODE HERE
    FROM tableName
    WHERE ...
    )x,

  (SELECT CASE
    WHEN ------CRITERIA FOR CODE HERE
    FROM tableName
    WHERE ...
    )z
```

Comment: it looks like joins that have no join criteria. do you intend it to be Cartesian join?

Comment: This question is very broad. Can you provide a more specific example, including the data structures you are using and the expected results? In addition, what you call "wrap" statements are more appropriately  called "Inline Views" or "Subqueries".

Answer (score 0):

When you do your sub-selects in the where clause like that, it essentially cross-joins them and that's not what you want.
If your "FROM tableName WHERE ..." part of each sub-select is identical, do them in the SELECT portion of the query, as follows:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN --criteria...) as c,
    (CASE WHEN --criteria...) as t,
    (CASE WHEN --criteria...) as x,
    (CASE WHEN --criteria...) as z
FROM tableName
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was originally thinking, just wanted to sum values from certain wrap statements into sum's from other wrap statements...Thanks!

Comment: You can sum each c, t, x, and z independently like this: `SUM(CASE WHEN ...) as c`

Answer (score 0):

The cross join is gonna duplicate records for you and your SUM will be adding up more than it should. That's why you are getting larger values than you expect.

If you post your full query, maybe we can help you with the rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I think your database is making a cross join of all the results of your sub-queries. Let me show you an example from SQLite:

```
sqlite> create table A(a,b);
sqlite> create table B(c,d);
sqlite> insert into B values ('1c','1d');
sqlite> insert into B values ('2c','2d');
sqlite> insert into A values ('1a','1b');
sqlite> insert into A values ('2a','2b');
sqlite> select a,b,c,d from A, B;
1a|1b|1c|1d
1a|1b|2c|2d
2a|2b|1c|1d
2a|2b|2c|2d
sqlite> select a,b from A;
1a|1b
2a|2b
sqlite> select c,d from B;
1c|1d
2c|2d
```

As you can see, tables A and B have both 2 rows. However select * from A, B produces 4 rows. That's because it creates every possible combination for rows from A and B. So when you sum() columns you get so big results.

You can try to do something like:

```
SELECT
  max(first_big_one_column_select),
  max(second_big_one_column_select),
  ...
```

But I'm not sure if it'll work. I think much depends on the database you're using.